# How to connect and execute a simple query to SQL Server from C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, sql-server, linux

I guess, I have all prerequisites for setting connection and querying `SQL Server` database, since I can do that from my `Python` code. And I do this like so:

```
#1. Set connection using pyodbc library

db = pyodbc('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER='+host+';PORT='+port+';DATABASE='+ \
            db_name+ ';UID='+ user+ ';PWD='+ pwd+ ';TDS_Version=7.0;ClientCharset=UTF8;') 

#2. List all table names in a particular database

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ' + db_name + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE ' + \
'TABLE_TYPE=\'BASE TABLE\'')
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

And I'm done. Now I want to implement the same thing, using `C++`. I've seen some sample codes like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2012/01/26/use-existing-msdn-c-odbc-samples-for-microsoft-linux-odbc-driver.aspx), but they look awfully terrible with five `if`s nested one into another. But I need something really simple, taking into consideration that probably all prerequisites are met (if may be not, please, instruct what else should be installed).

The last thing I want to know is indeed how to compile this program (I normally do this using `g++`). And, please, do not post sole references to `FreeTDS` and `ODBC` - I've already seen them. What I want at this stage is a tiny minimized example of executing the simplest in the world query (like I did it above, using `Python`).

Comment: I think you are better off looking for a C++ SQL client library. Something like http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_intro.htm

Comment: Why should not I use `FreeTDS`, if it already works in my `Python` programs?

Comment: Well I do not know that library but if has C++ bindings you can.

Comment: As for `otl`, I checked this examples page - http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl4_ex502.htm - and it really gets me crazy. For what reason to post such terrible examples which make absolutely no sense to starters? Where is simple connect example, where is simple select example, where simple instructions on how to compile a program. In Python it would normaly take me several minutes to start off with any library. Here I will have to spend several days trying to figure out what this stuff means. It would be much better, if there were teeny-weeny examples, comparable to Hello world

Comment: If you can provide all this and make a step-by-step answer from this, that will be greatly appreciated and worth +100500 of reputation from me and future starters.

Comment: I will start bounty in 20 hours, since I think it's a basic question and it needs some basic step-by-step working instructions. Connecting to SQL Server from `C++` should not be so hard, when you can do this from `Python`, especially taking into account what `FreeTDS` page says: "FreeTDS is a set of libraries for Unix and Linux that allows your programs to natively talk to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases." Therefore, I see no reason why it should be hundred times easier to connect from `Python`, than from `C++`.

Comment: Honestly, the MSDN example is pretty straightforward for C.  The nested ifs are just checking for error cases setting up database connection, and you can leave those out if you really want on an example (but never do this on production code).  I have the feeling you want C to be Python, but it's simply not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not tested with freetds driver of unixodbc.
This is how i setup unixodbc with postgres or mysql.
https://k3ut0i.github.io/work/2015-08-09-odbc-setup-linux.html

The global setup of drivers and data sources for ODBC are in `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini`. some operating systems may have these files empty or differenet names. Here are my config files.

Drivers, libraries in
/etc/odbcinst.ini file.

```
    [MySQL]
    Description     = ODBC driver for mariaDB
    Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc.so
    Setup           = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5S.so
    FileUsage       = 1
```

the pyodbc function in the python file is equivalent a data  source in
/etc/odbc.ini file.

```
    [mariadb-connector]
    Description     = connection to test database for mariadb
    Driver          = MySQL
    Database        = test
    Server          = 127.0.0.1
    UserName        = keutoi
    Trace           = No
    Port            = 3306
```

Part of the code that connects and query. I just started from your link and cleaned it up.

```
        /**
         * Connect to data source named in /etc/odbc.ini file
         */
        retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DSN=mariadb-connector;", SQL_NTS, outstr, sizeof(outstr), &outstrlen, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
        check_error(retcode, "connect to the data source");

        //Allocate statement handle
        retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
        check_error(retcode, "allocate a statement handle");

        /**
         * statement to be executed.
         */
        retcode = SQLExecDirect (hstmt, (SQLCHAR *) "select * from mytable", SQL_NTS);
        check_error(retcode, "execute the statement");

        /**
         * Bind a column to a variable
         */
        retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, szName, NAME_LEN, &cbName);
        check_error(retcode, "bind 1 column to the statement");
        retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, szID, ID_LEN, &cbID);
        check_error(retcode, "bind 2 column to the statement");

        /**
         * fetch sql hstmt untill there is no data and print
         */
        for (int i=0 ; ; i++)
        {
            retcode = SQLFetch(hstmt);
            if(retcode == SQL_NO_DATA)break;
            else printf( "%d: %s %s %s\n", i + 1, szID, szName);
        }
```

Complete example is [here](https://k3ut0i.github.io/work/2015-08-09-odbc-setup-linux.html). Compile with `g++ file.cc -lodbc`

Comment: Updating: Microsoft documentation to install ODBC on linux and OSX:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
And Example and Driver download from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Your need Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver for linux.

See big MSDN article https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Hh568454(v=SQL.110).aspx

Using C++ library example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2012/01/26/use-existing-msdn-c-odbc-samples-for-microsoft-linux-odbc-driver.aspx

Comment: "And, please, do not post sole references to FreeTDS and ODBC - I've already seen them." - this is a quote from my question. You not only reference ODBC, you even reference the very same example that I do in my question.